# How did Squirrel Girl defeat Dr Doom?

Tags: marvel, squirrel-girl, dr-doom

In [*Marvel Super Heroes* volume 2 #8](http://marvel.wikia.com/Marvel_Super-Heroes_Vol_2_8) (December 1991), Squirrel Girl defeated Dr. Doom by overwhelming him with a massive amount of Squirrels. How did this overwhelm Dr. Doom, who has been established as one of the premier villains in the Marvel Universe? Or more to the point, why did multiple squirrels attacking him distract him?

Also she has canonically defeated various other super villains; how?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, as to Dr. Doom, she overwhelmed him with something he wasn't ready for (think a zerg rush in your favorite MMORPG).. When you are armed to shoot down a bomber, 500,000 mosquitoes showing up instead can be an issue...

From the [Marvel Wiki entry](http://marvel.wikia.com/Doreen_Green_%28Earth-616%29):

> Hundreds of squirrels answered her call and flooded Doom's ship, chewing through the wires, and swamping the evil dictator with their furry bodies. Doom exclaimed "Confound these wretched rodents! For every one I fling away, a dozen more vex me!"

AS to other villains?  Yep..

Also from her entry:

> Thus far, Squirrel Girl has beaten: Doctor Doom, Mandarin, Giganto, M.O.D.O.K., Thanos, Terrax, Bug-Eyed Voice, Bi-Beast, Deadpool and Pluto.

And... lest you wonder if her victories couldn't be explained away (Doombots, dreams, etc...) the authors like to engage in [Lampshade Hanging](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging) with them, while clearly documenting their canon status. [image]

Also, see her entry at [TvTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SquirrelGirl), which contains one my favorite SG moments...

> It also creates a Crowning Moment of Funny when she goes to Latveria to borrow Dr. Doom's time machine. Doom just sighs and points her to the room, not even bothering to try and stop her.

Incidentally, if you check out her power stats on the [official Marvel.com page for her](http://marvel.com/universe/Squirrel_Girl) - they are ALL maxed; this puts her stats on par with various god-like beings such as the [Living Tribunal](http://marvel.com/universe/Living_Tribunal).  (Marvel.com, in this case, being about as solidly canon as can be hoped for.)

Comment: I've read those already, but they don't really give much in the way of explaining why that worked. I'd have thought someone like Doom or Thanos would have outclassed her in someway.

Comment: Yep; that's why they do it off screen.. It's never clearly indicated HOW she does it.. just that she does it.. She's a bit of a parody / throw back to Silver Age Comics / favorite of the writers.... so she accomplishes all sorts of stuff, but usually off-camera.

Comment: It's a universal rule of storytelling that the hero(ine) with the fewest advantages will always be the most likely to win. (Exception: the hero(ine) who deliberately tries to take advantage of this rule will always fail.)

Comment: I don't think you can zerg rush people in an MMORPG. Isn't that something you do in a very specific RTS?

Comment: @paul - Oh, you can certainly Zerg in an MMORPG.  It's one way an underpowered swarm of people can sometimes take out a larger boss.. That is one of the reasons a lot of MMORPGs restrict the number of players together against certain bosses by making 'instances' and limiting the number of people in each one.  Otherwise 2.2 billion level 1 players can take out things they really shouldn't be able to.  Also fun against an opposing faction, if your enemy doesn't have good area-effect damages.

Comment: How many billions of squirrels would have died to defeat Thanos... **DAMN ULTRA SQUIRREL GENOCIDE!!** She's a monster!

Comment: its totally a cruelty against animals, better call the PETA !!!

Comment: Now that it's 2019, we can add Kraven the Hunter, Galactus and Ultron to the list of villains she's successfully dealt with. (And on panel, to boot.)

Comment: Those stats were added by a fan and are not her official stats

Comment: @Valorum [The official Marvel site is not a fan wiki, and does list her stats at the bottom of the full profile as maxed.](https://www.marvel.com/characters/squirrel-girl-doreen-green/in-comics#power_grid-5)

Comment: @Mwr247 - You are mistaken. It was originally a fan-wiki and the article you're looking at (and the stats) were lifted directly from that article, written by a Marvel Discussion Forum Manager called Mimicx35; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/188077/20774. It's worthy of note that her official (from the Marvel Handbook) stats are much more closely aligned with what we see her doing in the comics

Comment: @Valorum Thank you for pointing that out. I had considered if such was the case, but saw no citation on the Marvel article or otherwise ability to edit. So it gave all impression of being official, which is rather unfortunate.

Comment: @Mwr247 - It certainly looks official and you're not the first to be fooled by it being hosted on Marvel's own homepage; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186899/does-squirrel-girl-have-maxed-power-stats-on-the-marvel-wiki?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment507923_186901. I was hoping to get some kind of comment from Marvel but they've been tight-lipped on the subject of the wiki for some time.