# How did Squirrel Girl defeat Thanos?

Tags: marvel, thanos, squirrel-girl

I was in a Marvel forum, and I saw a picture of Squirrel Girl with a defeated Thanos, and the Watcher saying that it was the real Thanos, and that she had saved the universe.

I'm not sure if that is a joke from Marvel, or it it is canon. In which comic did this happen?

Comment: related http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/how-did-squirrel-girl-defeat-dr-doom

Comment: Squirrels.  She defeated him with squirrels.

Comment: also defeated wolverine with squirrels its weird that she works has a babysitter for the avengers being so powerfull

Comment: @Keen, Squirrels, his one true weakness! And that of every single other villain in Marvel!

Comment: She defeated him with style and panache, of course...

Comment: @user3749635 She is no longer babysitter for Luke Cage and Jessica Jones. They left the New Avengers about 2 years ago at this point, so her services are no longer required.

Comment: that's bad i liked her where is she now?

Comment: It's often been said that her superpower is the ability to get the story to not focus on her, and then she can defeat the big guys without any need for logic. Another idea is that she just can't lose or, if she can, is just incredibly lucky.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This occurred in [GLX-MAS #1](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/3211/glx-mas_2005_1) published in 2005. It was a special holiday issue. The stories included are meant as parodies, and not canon within the main Marvel Universe.

[Marvel](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/3211/glx-mas_2005_1) describes the issue as such:

> Marvel’s own Milwaukee-based Misfits are back—in their very own, double sized X-mas special! Sure, they survived the GLA mini-series, but can Squirrel Girl, Mr. Immortal, and pals survive… the HOLIDAYS?!? 6 all-new features of mockery, morbidity, and merriment-- including the return of Grasshopper, Deathurge… and the Yuletide tyranny of Dr. Tannenbaum?!

There are actually two stories involved here.

The first is "Eggnog, Toilet Paper, & Peace on Earth". It ends with Squirrel Girl running to battle Thanos.

[image: Panel 1: A FEW MINUTES LATER... Squirrel Girl talking to Tippy-Toe, a squirrel, who is sitting on her shoulder. She says "So why didn't you remind me?" A spaceship is plummeting down in the background. Panel 2: The spaceship has landed and is smoking. Squirrel Girl says "What? A spaceship? Where? - Oh my! Look, Tippy-Toe! Something's coming out of it! Panel 3: A close-up on Thanos, with bright light shining from his hand. He says "YES! Once I, THANOS, have charged the Pyramatrix with the life force of everyone on Earth... - ...the universe will be mine for the taking!" Panel 4: Squirrel Girl charging forwards, saying "Oh yeah? Not if I can help it!" The comic ends with a circle panel of Tippy-Toe, with the caption TIPPY-TOE SAYS: "Here we go again!" THE END...?]

The second story is "Days of X-Mas Past". Unfortunately, it is never explained *how* Squirrel Girl defeated Thanos, just that she did.

[image: Thanos is lying on the ground, in the midst of destruction and flames. Squirrel Girl and Uatu the Watcher are standing there. UATU: "Congratulations, Squirrel Girl. By defeating Thanos, you have saved the entire multiverse. I wish I could have helped, but as a Watcher I am forbidden to interfere." SG: "Hey, that's okay, Uatu. Still, I can't believe that me and Tippy-Toe took out the REAL Thanos!" UATU: "Yes, Squirrel Girl, with my cosmic senses I can confirm that that is, in fact, the ONE TRUE THANOS, and not a robot, clone, or simulacrum."]

As to how Squirrel Girl *might* be able to defeat Thanos, one might refer to the answer to the question [How did Squirrel Girl defeat Dr Doom?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/how-did-squirrel-girl-defeat-dr-doom) which explains a possible battle strategy (Squirrel Swarming the enemy with extraordinary numbers) and points out the fact that her official power/ability stats are maxed out.

Comment: On the Facebook game **Marvel:Avengers Alliance** one of her power moves is (of course) a squirrel swarm (called Fury Furry).

Comment: I've never once heard from any official source that her victories aren't canon.

Answer (score 7):

Anyone who reads The Unbeatable Squirrel Girl knows that not only does she have superpowers (including super strength, super agility, claws, tail, knuckle spikes, ability to command a literal army of squirrels, ability to communicate with said squirrels, and some measure of invulnerability), she is also extremely intelligent (a computer science major who keeps up with her studies in addition to superheroics), pretty much angst-free (so not handicapped by her own emotions like so many superheroes) and, most importantly, she is allowed to have *common sense.*

Common sense is something most superheroes and supervillains lack.  She defeated Doc Doom twice by a combination of superpowers, intelligence, and sense.  Take any one of those qualities, especially sense, out of the equation, and you have a bog standard superhero or supervillain who does typically dumb things to advance the plot.  She is one of the few who is allowed to use all those positive talents in the same altercation.  If she can talk 'em down, she does.  If deliberately losing the battle means winning the war, well, she's done that, too.  Usually she just has creative strategies combined with intelligence, powers, and sense.

It used to be a common joke for a while that she beat the biggest of the big bads off-panel, though in her own comic we see her methods, which are sometimes conventional and sometimes quite wild and out there.  I imagine she beat Thanos because he got arrogant and over-confident, she got sneaky, and the squirrel army swarmed.

It's worth mentioning that later, in another comic, Thanos claimed she only beat a clone, despite what the Watcher said.  Who are you gonna believe?  The Watcher or the villain with the bruised ego?  LOL.  (Clone jokes come up frequently in TUSG comic, ridiculing this very bit of Thanosian ego)

Answer (score 1):

It's not Squirrel Girl, in this case, it's Thanos.

Thanos' biggest weakness is self-sabotage. Time after time, he will unwittingly hand his opponent(s) the means to defeat him because, deep down, he doesn't believe he deserves to win. Sometimes this manifests as simple plot device but there have been instances when his cohorts or those few he actually seeks out for advice have told this to his face, and left him silent.

Comment: Probably true. Could you include a reference to the comic, though?

Answer (score -4):

i feel like she's, for lack of a better term, squirrely and spry, just as much as her furry friends, it's possible that just like a squirrel she would be pretty much impossible to catch and most likely can tire/frustrate her opponent to the point where even the toughest most cunning villain will eventually make a mistake and open to attack, she reminds me of deadpool in the sense that there is a method to their madness

Comment: Do you have references?

Comment: Welcome to Sci-fi and Fantasy Stack Exchange. Unless you can provide some sort of a source for this it is not an answer that adheres to answers generally acceptable on this site. Please only provide answers that provide some sort of proven or reference-able conclusion.