# Has Thanos ever been defeated?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thanos

I already know that in some comics he cannot die as a result of Death barring him from her realm. But has he ever been defeated in combat by one person or a group of people? 
I'm only wondering because they'll have to get rid of him somehow in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

Comment: “they'll have to get rid of him somehow in the MCU...” — unless the series is about to take a really dark turn.

Comment: Damn I hope not!

Comment: If you’re not keen on dark stories, I suggest you don’t read *Marvel Zombies* or *Old Man Logan*.

Comment: Sort of a dupe of [How did Squirrel Girl defeat Thanos?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63231/how-did-squirrel-girl-defeat-thanos), but GLX-Mas was a non-canon story.

Comment: Isn't Thanos mostly a "sitting bully"?

Comment: What happened when you looked this up on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos)?

Comment: Bad guys are always defeated, even when they are clearly superior and unbeatable.  This is what makes super hero stories great.  It also makes them annoyingly unrealistic, even though they are entertaining and addicting!

Comment: Why has Apocalypse not conquered the world?  He is thousands of years old, is immortal, and possesses the power to morph into anything and destroy anything.  Plus he can fly and instantly teleport.  Somehow, he always gets defeated :)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It's not that I'm not keen on dark stories, I just don't like it when it starts off alright and takes a turn for the worse... I like my dystopian stuff to start off being dystopian x)
Also I've been wanting to read Marvel Zombies for a WHILE now, I was gonna buy them all on Amazon, are they any good?

Comment: @Y.G.: yeah they’re pretty good fun, and like Old Man Logan they start dystopian.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Just how I like 'em! Haha I'll try to read them sometime soon :)

Comment: @Brandon - just depends on what timeline you're looking at. Technically, Apocalypse has conquered the world several times.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Yes, he has been defeated.**

- In *Avengers Assemble #1-8* he returned to earth but the Avengers along with the Guardians of the Galaxy teamed up and beat him.

[image]

- He has also been stopped by [Adam Warlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Warlock) in Avengers Annual #7

[image]

- In the [Infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_(comic_book)) storyline Thanos is trapped in a pocket limbo of stasis by his son (Infinity #6)

[image]

- (On Earth 616) he has been defeated by the [Mangog](http://marvel.wikia.com/Mangog_(Earth-616)) (Thor Annual Vol 2 #2000)

[image]

- He has been beaten by Drax on the Annihilation series.

[image]

Here is his punch:

[image]

Comment: Don't forget Drax. He actually managed to punch a hole through Thanos' chest.

Comment: The word balloon sums Thanos up perfectly.  "Interesting", he says.  It must've been just a flesh wound.

Comment: Who is that pixie on Thano's shoulder and why does she seem offended?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas http://marvel.com/characters/2130/skreet

Comment: @WilliamJackson So basically an evil Wasp Girl?

Answer (score 65):

He has also been defeated by Squirrel Girl (GLX-Mas Special--December 2005), though I doubt that will come up in the movie universe.

[image]

Comment: This was gonna be my answer. Have an upvote!

Comment: Aye, I was about to complain the accepted answer was missing an entry.

Comment: Technically, Thanos has implied that it WAS a clone, because he'd perfected a technique so that not even cosmic beings (such as Watchers) could detect it. If that's the case, Uatu was fooled and Squirrel Girl defeated a weak clone. Considering her skill set, that's the most likely scenario.

Comment: Pfft, that's just Thanos covering for getting beat up by Squirrel Girl :U

Comment: @CreationEdge Or the Thanos who said that was a clone, replacing the real Thanos (who was killed by Squirrel Girl),

Comment: We can't possibly know unless someone invents a clone detector that can detect clones that fool even high cosmic beings! Or, the entire thing gets retconned. It could go either way, really.

Comment: @CreationEdge - you mean a clone-detector that detects undetectable clones?

Comment: @Omegacron Undetectable clones implies you can't detect them at all! We want to detect that they are clones, when even high cosmic beings are convinced they're the real deal.

Answer (score -5):

As per the movie Dr. strange. Thanos is defeated in a way by Dr. strange and I believe that's the best way it's shown. Thanos the mad titan is not worth an enemy. The beyonder would be the greatest enemy.

Comment: If you're referring to the villain of Dr Strange, that was Dormammu, not Thanos.