# Is Thanos immortal?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

I don’t think I have seen or read anything implying Thanos couldn’t be killed, which begs the question: **Why didn’t Iron Man, Doctor Strange, Spider-Man, Star Lord, Mantis and Nebula simply kill Thanos when they had him immobilized?**

It was the first and likely the last time they had him immobilized and unable to defend himself,  so instead of wasting all that time trying to remove the Infinity Gauntlet, that seemed impossible to remove, they could have killed him in a myriad of ways. He bleeds like any man, therefore he can die. He even tells Thor that head trauma would have prevented him from snapping his fingers. Iron Man had that cool nano tech sword and could have decapitated him; Drax could have stabbed him through the heart with his long knives; Star Lord could have just pushed the barrel of his pistol against his head and pulled the trigger.

It would have been far more effective than pistol whipping him which only woke him from the trance Mantis had him in. I mean that if he’s dead, he wouldn’t have been able to snap his fingers. You have probably heard the saying “You can have my gun when you pry my cold dead fingers off of it” That seems to be the way Thanos feels about the Infinity Gauntlet, so even if they had been successful in removing the gauntlet he would have done anything and everything to get it back and would only quit when he was dead.

The very obvious answer is that the movie would have been a lot shorter and there would be no sequel *Avengers: End Game* movie, but other than that, why didn’t they simply decapitate him or stab him through the heart? (Or any of a myriad of other ways.)

Comment: Well, he took an asteroid to the face and walked away because of the glove. Sure Thanos was a huge threat without the glove, but with it the danger was exponentially compounded. And the plan worked perfectly until Quill messed it up. As far as him being immortal, I think he is just as far as we would consider the Asgardians immortal. Also, in the end Thor did try, but because of the it was near futile...

Comment: Not sure if I should mark this as duplicate. But in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63231/how-did-squirrel-girl-defeat-thanos) everything is answered. I'm also not sure, it is the same universe.

Comment: It's worth noting that "Is Thanos immortal?" and "Why didn't they try and kill Thanos when they had him immobilised" are two different questions.

Comment: In the immortal words of Big Arnie; ["*If it bleeds, we can kill it*"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNr0WXQ3Ho4)

Comment: "He bleeds like any man." I haven't seen any man, or any human being for that matter, who takes that much to make them bleed.

Comment: “He even tells Thor that head trauma would have prevented him from snapping his fingers” — head trauma *from Stormbreaker*. A weapon that Thor withstood the fire of a sun to obtain, because it could kill Thanos. That fairly strongly implies that other, lesser weapons could not kill Thanos.

Answer (score 3):

The Power Stone makes him nearly invulnerable (see GOtG where Ronan gets smashed by a ship at high speed and a missile launcher that "can destroy a small moon" and survives with barely a scratch, and he was less powerful than Thanos before he possessed the stone.) So they tried to remove the Gauntlet and then they could relatively easily take him out. Thor was able to nearly kill him with Stormbreaker because it's made of enchanted Uru, which is the same stuff the Gauntlet is made of, and is immensely powerful.