# What are Squirrel Girl's 'actual' stats? Is she truly the most powerful being in the Marvel universe?

Tags: marvel, squirrel-girl

On the [Marvel Universe Wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Squirrel_Girl#axzz5EPq4uFgz) ("*The Definitive online source for Marvel super hero bios*") Squirrel Girl is listed as having the maximum stats in her [power grid](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Grid).

However in the [Official Marvel Handbook (2002 - Avengers Edition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe#Publication_history) ("*Comprehensive and exhaustive*") she's listed as having lower stats.

[image]

### **Which one is correct and why is there a discrepancy?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Squirrel Girl have maxed power stats on the Marvel Wiki?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186899/does-squirrel-girl-have-maxed-power-stats-on-the-marvel-wiki)

Comment: @Adamant - The only part of any of the answers that address this question is Edlothiad's supposition ("*it is possible this is a joke in part from marvel about a superhero with Squirrel powers being one of the most powerful beings in the galaxy.*") but that's hardly the sort of hard, definitive answer that this site demands.

Comment: Well, to be honest, you also basically answer your question *in* the question, but there’s not precisely a close reason for that. Any answer to this question and the other one will basically provide the same information, and they’re the same basic question at heart (“Are Squirrel Girl’s stats really this high?”)

Comment: @Adamant - To my mind a good answer would find sources that explain why they're different (which is what I'm asking for). It would probably also address which has the higher canon status and who the authors were

Comment: I struggle to see how these may be dupes. The answers are significantly different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Squirrel Girl's stats on the Marvel Wiki are not considered to be canon. As with all entries on that site they were written by fans rather than being a curated collection of facts written by Marvel staff.

In this case, her article and stats were written by a comic-book fan named Kyle Nichols (aka [Mimicx35](http://marvel.com/universe/User:Mimicx35#axzz5G3sjjrjJ)). He's contributed to multiple articles but I see no evidence that he has any special relationship with Marvel other than being a keen reader of comics and running several now-defunct comic chatrooms on MSN in the 1990s. A Marvel staffer did stop by to make a cosmetic change to her article (adding a better quality photo) but that's about it.

---

Her actual stats, as seen in the [Official Marvel Handbook of the Universe - Avengers 2005 edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe) are those that are considered to be canonically valid and, crucially, actually fit with what we actually see her doing in the comics.

> [image]
>
> Intelligence - Human normal
> Strength - Superhuman (lift 800 lbs-25 ton range)
> Speed - Superhuman (peak range: 700 MPH)
> Durability - Enhanced
> Energy Projection - None
> Fighting Skills - Experienced fighter

These are replicated in a later edition, the [2008 Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A-Z (2008)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A-Z_Vol_1) where she is described as a "*surprisingly fierce and formidable unarmed combatant*".

[image]

And again in the [Women of Marvel: Celebrating Seven Decades](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/32511/women_of_marvel_celebrating_seven_decades_2010_1_variant/variant) handbook (2010).

[image]

along with a brief description of her strength and agility

[image]

If I had a Marvel wiki login, I'd edit these into her article.

Comment: Geez, 800 - 50000 pounds is a huge strength range. I'm assuming she's at the low end of that.

Comment: @CreationEdge - Her strength is portrayed extremely variably, but in general she's at least as strong as Spider-Man. She can leap tall buildings and break Rhino's grip; https://www.reddit.com/r/respectthreads/comments/61ikf2/respect_the_unbeatable_squirrel_girl_marvel_616/. That puts her in the 10-15 ton range.

Comment: She didn't break Rhino's grip. She slammed into his chest and he let go. Much different.

Comment: @CreationEdge  -That's fair. The Women of Marvel handbook puts her strength range in at "1 Ton" but notes that she has special jumping ability.

Answer (score 9):

Squirrel Girl's incredible power and ability started as a running joke in Dan Slott's Great Lake Avengers books - we were presented with a series of aftermaths of staggering battles, including one where she defeats Thanos, and The Watcher even shows up to verify that it's totally the real Thanos.

[image]

This all springs from the fact that in Squirrel Girl's first appearance (written by Will Murray and drawn by Steve Freakin' Ditko) she defeated Doctor Doom. It's an in-canon story, and it's been cemented in continuity that it was the REAL Doom, not a Doombot, or any of the narrative "outs" that had been used in the past to explain away losses by powerful characters

[image]

Slott's use of the character gave her quite the push, and when she started showing up in Avengers, she became an "A-Level" hero. Now she's got her own book, and will be appaearing in the New Warriors show, played by Milana Vayntrub, AKA Lily from AT&T.

Is she REALLY all that powerful and "unbeatable"? Probably not.  Is she undeniably awesome? You bet your nut-sack.

Comment: But it addresses the second half of the question in the headline, which I thought would be useful.

Comment: In a later comic, set earlier, Thanos reveals he learned to make clones that could fool even cosmic beings, AKA it invalidates the Watcher's comments here.

Comment: @CreationEdge: Right... he probably keeps that process with his Canadian girlfriend who's actually a model and plays videogames with him all the time, but it's traveling, so you can't meet her.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It's canon...  https://www.cbr.com/the-abandoned-an-forsaked-did-squirrel-girl-just-beat-up-the-real-thanos/

Comment: @CreationEdge: Huh. I'd always figured it was a panel of him simply making that claim, but they do rather flesh it out.

Comment: There's a long list of "No it isn't" entries in comics where a later writer will explicitly add a point that will undo a particular plot event that a previous creator did.  My favorite was when they un-did the John Byrne Thing story where he claimed Lockjaw could talk. YEARS later, another writer tossed in a throwaway line that it was a practical joke on Ben Grimm.

Answer (score 4):

Squirrel Girl's stats from IGN's [Marvel Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Heroes_(video_game)) role-playing game seems to agree with the Official Marvel Handbook (though using a somewhat different scale), indicating that the OMH has the right stats.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that these are in any way canonical? They seem to differ enough to seem to be based on one another, but not identical.