# Has the Marvel power grid been completely removed from their website? I cannot find it anywhere

Tags: marvel

Has the Marvel power grid been completely removed from their website?  I cannot find it anywhere... does anyone have a link to one?

Answer (score 3):

It's not there for every character, but you'll find it under "[*In Comics Full Report*](https://www.marvel.com/characters/captain-america-steve-rogers/in-comics)", sometimes at the top of the page and sometimes at the bottom.

They've also changed it from a grid to a series of circles.

[image]

Comment: What’s the Marvel Power Grid if I may ask?

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Power_Grid

Comment: thanks for the info!

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - There are some examples here; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/188077/20774