# Is there an in-universe reason for why Squirrel Girl is so powerful?

Tags: marvel, squirrel-girl

The title more or less says it all. Squirrel Girl is generally referred to as the "Unbeatable Squirrel Girl," and her record backs this up as it includes the likes of Doctor Doom and Thanos.

**Is there any in-universe explanation for why she's so powerful, or is it just a out-of-universe running joke that never gets explained in-universe?**

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186899/does-squirrel-girl-have-maxed-power-stats-on-the-marvel-wiki) and [very closely related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186975/58193).

Comment: I _could_ write a good answer when I get home because I remember a panel where Deadpool literally said those fights don't count in continuity. But marking as a duplicate might be more appropriate.

Comment: It's because she's nuts.

Comment: Squirrel Girl isn't "unbeatable" because she is brimming with raw power. She wins through a combination of luck, determination, personality (she frequently reasons her foes out of their villainy, for instance), intelligence, and her use of unexpected tactics (like swarming a foe with squirrels).

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186899/does-squirrel-girl-have-maxed-power-stats-on-the-marvel-wiki) and [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186975/what-are-squirrel-girls-actual-stats-is-she-truly-the-most-powerful-being-in) go into the details of Squirrel Girl's power stats, which started as a joke in various Marvel books. I'm going to answer from the perspective of the [Unbeatable Squirrel Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unbeatable_Squirrel_Girl) series written by Ryan North and illustrated (until very recently) by Erica Henderson.

In this series, it's shown multiple times that Squirrel Girl "defeats" her opponents by talking to them, understanding them, and either befriending them or outsmarting them.

For example this is how she "defeats" Galactus:

[image: Squirrel Girl and Galactus]

She has a similar approach to Kraven:

[image: Squirrel Girl and Kraven]
<sub>(source: [i2.wp.com](https://i2.wp.com/comicsbulletin.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Peta.png))</sub>

These are the in-universe explanations of how Squirrel Girl defeats such strong opponents, but a lot of the earlier mentions were more of a joke than anything else.

Related:

- [How did Squirrel Girl defeat Dr Doom?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8454/26220)
- [How did Squirrel Girl defeat Thanos?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63231/26220)

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question of how she's so powerful. More just adds a way of how she's defeated some and who she's defeated.