# Is Squirrel Girl's "power" intentionally over-exaggerated, like One-Punch Man?

Tags: marvel, squirrel-girl, one-punch-man

Reading the following questions and answers:

[Is there an in-universe reason for why Squirrel Girl is so powerful?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/189011/136731)

[Does Squirrel Girl have maxed power stats on the Marvel Wiki?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186899/136731)

[What are Squirrel Girl's 'actual' stats? Is she truly the most powerful being in the Marvel universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186975/136731)

[How did Squirrel Girl defeat Dr Doom?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8454/136731)

[How did Squirrel Girl defeat Thanos?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63231/136731)

I was left with two impressions:

- Either [Squirrel Girl](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Doreen_Green_(Earth-616)) is obnoxiously powerful like [*One-Punch Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-Punch_Man) as an intentional joke (e.g., per the Marvel Wiki stats linked in some of the above Q&As, suggesting she's stronger and smarter than uber villains like [Thanos](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thanos_(Earth-616))).  That is, the writers made her stupidly strong and have her beat high-end villains like Thanos and [Dr. Doom](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Victor_von_Doom_(Earth-616)) as a mocking joke (to other characters?) since one would not expect such an unassuming character to actually win such fights.
- Or she's not actually super strong or super smart and even the in-universe examples of where she defeated a super villain were one-off flukes of luck (i.e., Would she really be able to defeat Doom twice?  The squirrel-blitz tactic may have worked once, but such a person would certainly create safeguards and protocols to prevent such an event from ever happening again, would they not?).

So, is Squirrel Girl actually powerful as an intentional joke, kind of like the entire premise of *One-Punch Man*?

Comment: It feels like this is going to overlap a lot with the other questions you've linked. Is there much to say that hasn't already been said there?

Comment: @IMSoP - It certainly seems like a dupe of the middle one.

Comment: @Valorum - I am not asking what are her actual stats.  I am asking whether she has been jokingly overpowered or if she has legitimate wins that are just one-off flukes of luck.  I agree it's subtle but I am more trying to gauge whether all of her wins are just jokes along the same premise as the One-Punch Man gimmick.

Comment: Her schtick is that she's unbeatable. It literally says it in the title.

Comment: @Valorum - Yes, I gathered that (well her title at least) but is it meant to be serious or some sort of joke.  My take on One-Punch Man is that it's meant to mock over-powered superheroes while also putting a spin on the juxtaposition of his absurd power with his apathetic and unassuming personality.  The combination makes for decent-to-good humor and some entertaining humiliation.  So my question is, is Squirrel Girl meant to be taken the same way?  If not, why don't The Avengers just throw her at every problem?

Comment: @honeste_vivere - in the future she's the head of the Avengers, so maybe they do throw her at every problem!

Comment: @Valorum - Seriously?  Jeez, I am so far behind on all this stuff.  I read comics as a kid but have zero time as an adult ;P

Comment: @honeste_vivere - [Squirrel Girl Vol.5 #16](https://www.marvel.com/comics/collection/60372/the_unbeatable_squirrel_girl_vol_5_like_im_the_only_squirrel_in_the_world_tpb_trade_paperback) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nza6Z.jpg

Comment: I've always interpreted it as a meta thing: she stars in the kind of comic books where the good guys always win, and she's the good guy. Therefore, by narrative necessity, she'll always eventually win.